# How to edit php code in github desktop and display it in browser

Tags: php, git, github

Greeting, i am really new to github. My lecturer send me a php project in github. He ask me to edit and send the project URL to him. i don't know how to do it without he know that i am edit it. I don't want that he notice while i edit :D. I hope there is anyone to guide me. Thanks a lot. I cannot ask my lecturer this question because he ask us to try by own.

Comment: I think first you should spend a hour or so getting familiar with basic GIT, then this will become very simple to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first read about git basics: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

At second watch this: https://desktop.github.com/ (help page: https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/), this is GUI wrapper over git. If you terrified of the terminal, use this.

Full way:
Clone repo -> Switch to the **new branch** -> Make some changes (edit file for example) -> Commit this changes -> Push changes to **new branch** -> Checkout back to master branch -> Merge your **new branch** to master -> Push -> ??? -> Done

Comment: <h1>Thanks a lot </h1> @Qteb i will follow it